# StringFormat not show delimiter in decimal numbers

Tags: php, string-formatting

This is what i have try:

```
 <Label Content="{Binding number, StringFormat=N2}"
```

In case my number is `1320` i want to see `1,320` but it still `1320` although i also try

```
<Label Content="{Binding number, StringFormat={}{0:#,0}}"
```